# Why does GetMethod need BindingFlags as mandatory information in order to find methods?

Tags: c#, reflection

Assuming I have this class with a private method:

```
public class Test
{
    private void Method()
    {
    }
}
```

And this code:

```
var method1 = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method"); // null
var method2 = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); // works!!
var method3 = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method",BindingFlags.Instance); // null
```

1. Why are `method1` and `method3` null?
2. Why do I have to be specific with the `BindingFlags` in order to actually get the method?
    If it's because I can have multiple methods with the same name then what does the `GetMethods` exist for?
3. How specific do I need to be? In this case I needed to add that I'm looking for a non-public & instance method. Since not all of the `BindingFlags` values are straight forward, how do I know where I need to stop?

Comment: The method `Method` is private so you have to include `NonPublic`. The default is `Public | Static | Instance`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - `var method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.NonPublic);` is null as well. I need to add that the method is also an instance method in order to get the methodinfo.

Comment: If you don't use the defaults you have to specify *all* the values of the enum. The default is to include public methods which are static or instance methods. If you specify the parameter you have to specify whether to include public or static methods, if you don't you get neither.

Comment: Sure, you also need the `Instance` flag.

Comment: Ok - but why do I need to add that information? I would expect the `GetMethod` to return the first match and the `GetMethods` to return a collection of matches. I would also expect the `BindingFlags` to be a filter on the results. I use this method a lot and I know how to "make it work" - but I always ask myself why do I need to be so specific? 
Thank you for you answers.

Comment: The result *is* filtered. For instance, if you don't want to include inherited members then you add `DeclaredOnly`. Now, if you invoke `GetMethods` it will not include `ToString`, `GetHashCode` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Private modifier means "hide this method from outsiders", so by default GetMethods() returns only the public members.

1.method1 and method3 are null because it is specifically mentioned in [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that **"You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or no members will be returned."**

2.For using reflection you must know exactly what you are looking for otherwise you might get the wrong method to invoke.

3.As I already mentioned in No.1 answer, you must at-least specify "Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic".